# What is the formula to calculate parallel efficiency of map reduce algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, parallel-processing, mapreduce

Is there any formula which can tell us parallel efficiency of map reduce algorithm? (in other words how I can mathematically prove that MR algorithm A is better than MR algorithm B)

I googled it but I could find just the definition of speed-up and efficiency for parallel algorithms on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup) but it will be good if someone can show how those formulas are applied to MR algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Wiki [for `Bulk Synchronous Parallel` in short `BSP`.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_synchronous_parallel)

Another complexity calculation is included in Rob Bisselings paper

> Parallel Scientific Computation: A Structured Approach Using BSP and
>   MPI

`BSP` is the abstraction to `MapReduce` and contains complexity/cost analysis formulaes at the bottom of the link.

So what you need to do is, convert your `MapReduce` algorithm to the `BSP` version. Barrier Synchronizations are for example the transition between `Map` and `Reduce` stages or a new `MapReduce` Job. Messages (communication) are what you emit to the filesystem in your `Map` and `Reduce`function.